# Import Linkedin profile image in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, photo, linkedin-api, user-profile

I need to show user's Linkedin profile image in my ASP.NET application. The user need to login to Linkedin in a popup window and then my ASP.NET application will extract image from the Linkedin profile and display with username onto my asp.net website.